# Parametric field Plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, parametric-functions

i want to plot this field:
G(x,y,z) = (0,0,-b^3(x^2+y^2)cos(b^2(x^2+y^2)))
with the parameter b>0.
Is it possible to do that? if yes,how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will plot the vector field $G$ and allow you to vary $b$:

```
Manipulate[
 VectorPlot3D[{0, 0, -b^3 (x^2 + y^2) Cos[b^2 (x^2 + y^2)]},
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
 , {b, 0.01, 3}]
```

Comment: thank you. may i ask you if can i combine it with that plot ? ContourPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + 100*(z - 11)^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 11, 
  11.3}]

Comment: Put the plots in a `Show` i.e using `Show[plot1, plot2]`. `VectorPlot3D`'s styles like VectorSize don't behave very well in v12.1 so it might look a bit extruded due to the range of the first plot.

Comment: it is doesnt work, i wrote that code: p1 = Manipulate[
   VectorPlot3D[{0, 0, -b^3 (x^2 + y^2) Cos[b^2 (x^2 + y^2)]}, {x, -1,
      1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 11, 11.3}], {b, 0.01, 3}];
p2 = ContourPlot3D[
   x^2 + y^2 + 100*(z - 11)^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 11, 
    11.3}];
Show[p1, p2]

Comment: @amit you can't put the manipulate in there - it should go on the outside. Do this: `Manipulate[
 Show[
  ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + 100*(z - 11)^2 == 1,
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 11, 11.3}],
  VectorPlot3D[{0, 0, -b^3 (x^2 + y^2) Cos[b^2 (x^2 + y^2)]},
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 11, 11.3}, VectorSizes -> .3, 
   VectorPoints -> 6]]
 , {b, 0.01, 3}]`